# Full Calendar - MinMax Time+SlotDuration Not Show Hours Column

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using fullcalendar v2.9.1 and I would like to show the calendar with slotDuration of '00:90:00' and maxTime: "22:00:00", minTime: "08:00:00".

But the calendar not show the hours in the left column.

When I removed the min/max time, I noticed that there is no hour of 8am, only 6:30 and 9:00 (because of slotDuration of 90 min).

Here's the settings:

```
views: {
    agendaOneDay: {
      type: 'agenda',
      duration: { days: 1 },
      // buttonText: '2 day',
      weekends: false,
      columnFormat: 'ddd M/D'
    }
  },
  timezone: "local",
  header: false,
  height: calendarService.getCalendarHeightViaScreenSize(contact),
  slotDuration: '00:90:00',
  slotEventOverlap: false,
  // slotLabelInterval: '02:00:00',
  defaultView: device_type_mobile ? 'agendaOneDay' : 'agendaWeek',
  eventBackgroundColor: 'white',
  eventTextColor: '#3f51b5',
  firstDay: 1,
  weekends: false,
  selectable: true,
  eventOverlap: false,
  selectOverlap: contact ? true : false,
  editable: contact ? false : true,
  maxTime: "22:30:00",
  minTime: "08:00:00",
  axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
  allDaySlot: false
```

Can someone help me on this regard, please?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use moment.js:

```
slotDuration: moment.duration('00:90:00'),
```

Even that, it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never too late...

> On "maxTime:"  | type "string" is not assignable

You need to write:

```
minTime: duration("hh:mm:ss"),
maxTime: duration("hh:mm:ss"),
```